# UART Tx Shorted to 3.3V

Tags: uart

I'm using a PIC32mx470 and trying to get the UART communication running. I was having some issues and noticed that the Tx pin has continuity with the 3.3V lines in the circuit. Is this something that the chip does when UART is enabled? Or is it likely a short somewhere?

I've tested continuity on 3 other boards and none of them have continuity between Tx and 3.3V, but I haven't enabled UART on any of them.

Edit: I tested continuity using a multimeter with the board powered on and off. I also probed Tx with a scope and it stayed at 3.3V with no signs of UART messages.

Comment: How did you measure continuity? If with a multimeter, please understand that different multimeters measure it differently and have different limits for determining continuity or no continuity. And you can't measure continuity on non-linear circuits such as ICs, at least not when powered up. Please update how you determined continuity.

Comment: @Justme updated question above: I tested continuity using a multimeter with the board powered on and off. I also probed Tx with a scope and it stayed at 3.3V with no signs of UART messages.

Comment: CMOS  pins usually protected by clamping diodes to the rails. So it is highly likely that you will see "continuity" at least in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

When enabled, UART will idle at logic high level, so it is normal that it idles at 3.3V level on 3.3V MCU.

It is unlikely to be shorted to 3.3V, but on the other hand, it's a CMOS output, so you can kind of think that the push-pull output stage P-FET does short the output pin to 3.3V intentionally to make the pin a high output.

Also, you can't use continuity testing on MCU pins. Or if you do, you have to know what your multimeter really measures when testing continuity, and from that measurement, how does it decide if it is considered as continuity or no continuity. Refer to multimeter manual.